# Is there anything like MAMP for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to learn Ruby on Rails. I would like a development environment that doesn't install live on my laptop, I would like a self-contained install similar to what MAMP is for PHP. Is there such a thing?

I'm not looking to cram Ruby on Rails into MAMP, I don't much like mucking with the terminal nowdays. I'm looking for a nice and easy to use, download and play with Ruby on Rails in a self contained system.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you are using a mac.  If you are on windows life will be difficult unfortunately.  You can try out [http://railsinstaller.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130717114947/http://railsinstaller.org:80/)

Answer (score 2):

One of these preconfigured VMs should be what you're looking for:
http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/rails

And a great benifit of a VM is that you can easily move it over to another system, or even use it in a production scenario. Also, they are of course OS agnostic.